# C# - Active Directory - Add a list of Groups (G1) to another Group (G2) only by knowing some attribute (entityID's are G1)

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a list of groups (we'll call it G1) that I need to add to another group (G2). I only know the EntityID's of the groups that will be added to G2.

At first, I thought I would go about it with something like so...

```
foreach (string facilityID in facilitiesIDList)
{
   try
   {
      using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "server_name.net"))
      {
         GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
         GroupPrincipal fac = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, facilityID);

         if (fac == null)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Facility Not Found: {0}", facilityID);
         }

         group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, facilityID);
         group.Save();

         sblog.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}\tINFO\tAdded {1} to group {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString(dtformat), facilityID, groupName));
         hasChangedData = true;
      }
   }
```

But then I realized that that `GroupPrincipal.Members.Add(blah,IdentityType.HERE, blah)` didn't have a way to use some sort of LDAP filter with it.

So I know I will have to go about this another way, however, I am unsure of how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks